# Reordering values in a multi value field

Tags: 7

Is there a module that allows you to reorder the values of a multi value field?  By drag and drop or by weight.

Example:

```
Field XYZ:
+ Value 1
+ Value 2
+ Value 3
+ Value 4
```

Reorder to:

```
Field XYZ:
+ Value 4
+ Value 2
+ Value 3
+ Value 1
```

Comment: You think fields as in fieldable entities? O form api elements?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in the context of adding/editing nodes, Drupal 7 core provides this functionality on node add/edit pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try [Multiple value widget](https://drupal.org/project/multiple_value_widget) module.

> Drupal utilizes draggable tables to handle multiple value forms. It's
>   quite convenient for most simple field types. However, for complex
>   field types such form can be cumbersome. For example, the widget for
>   Image field type can contain a preview of a file, an upload button, a
>   text field for title and alt attributes. Sometimes you have a lot of
>   images to be uploaded and the form takes up a lot of space.

*This module integrates the jQuery UI tabs and accordion plugins as a replacement for draggable tables to make multiple value forms more user friendly. All field items can still be ordered through jQuery UI sortable widget.*